# Uploading a file on non input type="file"

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to upload a file using Puppeteer, but, the thing is there is no `<input type="file">`, as a result, the following code fails:-

```
let input = await page.$("input[type=file]");
await input.uploadFile("./test.pdf");
```

There are some other input fields, but, uploading on them also fails with the following error:-

> Error: Protocol error (DOM.setFileInputFiles): Node is not a file
>   input element

The following is the code of the upload button:-

```
<form name="commonform" id="form_bookinteriorPrimaryForm" method="post" action="https://tsw.createspace.com/title/ajax/paperback/8871655/setup/book_interior/processservice?serviceId=88073343&amp;serviceKey=bookinterior&amp;taskKey=book_interior&amp;submittedBy=4241370&amp;pageCount=120">
<div class="task" id="task123780522">
<div class="action FILE_UPLOAD" id="t123780522a_interiorfile">
<input type="hidden" id="form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_s3name" name="TSW_BOOK_INTERIOR-">
<input type="hidden" id="form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_asyncTaskPostfix" name="t123780522a_interiorfile_asyncTaskPostfix">
<span class="formFieldContainer" id="form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadComplete" style="display: none;">
       <div class="contentFormLabel">
          <span>Interior File</span>
       </div>
   <div class="contentFormField">
<span id="form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadUserFileName" class="uploadFileName">interior - Copy.pdf</span><br>
        <a href="https://tsw.createspace.com/title/8871655/setup/book_interior#" target="" class="changeUploadLink" onclick="universalAjaxHandler.handleOnClick([['element', 'form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadComplete', 'hide'], ['element', 'form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadEdit', 'show']]); return false;"><span class="">Upload a different file</span></a>
<div class="clearer"></div>
      <br>
   </div>
</span>
<span class="fixedFormUploadEdit" id="form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadEdit" style="">
<div id="t123780522a_interiorfile_upload_field_containerTop" class="cspContainerTop" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="t123780522a_interiorfile_upload_field_container" class="cspContainer">
<div id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_field_container" class="cspContainer formFieldContainer">
    <div class="contentFormLabel">
<span class="">Interior File</span>
       <span class="requiredColor">*</span>
    </div>
<div class="contentFormField">
<span id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadIFrame" style="display: none;">
</span>
<span id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadSWF" style="">
   <div style="float: left;">
      <input type="text" class="contentTextField formItemNormal" id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadTextTarget" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 5px;" disabled="true">
   </div>
   <div style="float: left;">
      <div class="round_button_link" id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadUploadContainer">
         <div class="round_button_link_left"></div>
         <div class="round_button_link_middle">
            <div style="margin-top: 4px;">Browse</div>
         </div>
         <div class="round_button_link_right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</span>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<span class="note">The following formats are accepted: pdf,doc,docx,rtf</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (window.CSP_OK) {
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function(e) {
         blockHandler = false;
   new FormInputField('tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadTextTarget');
      });
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
   <div id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results" class="cspError contentFormError" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (window.CSP_OK) {
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function(e) {
         blockHandler = false;
   new FormField('tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_field_container');
      });
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
   <div class="clearer"></div>
    <div id="t123780522a_interiorfile_upload_results" class="cspError formFieldDefaultError" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (window.CSP_OK) {
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function(e) {
         blockHandler = false;
   new FormField('t123780522a_interiorfile_upload_field_container');
      });
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
   <br>
</span>
<div class="cspError formFieldDefaultError" style="display: none;padding-left:50px;" id="form_bookinterior_clientside_failure">
   Please check your internet connection and try again. We highly recommend using a high-speed broadband Internet connection.
</div>
<div class="clearer">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (window.CSP_OK) {
      document.observe('dom:loaded', function(e) {
         blockHandler = false;
    window['form_bookinterior_interiorfile'] = new AjaxFixedFormUpload(
        'form_bookinterior_interiorfile', 'form_bookinterior_upload_tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload', 'form_bookinterior', '123780522', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload', '/title/ajax/paperback/8871655/setup/book_interior/validateupload',
        '/title/ajax/paperback/8871655/setup/book_interior/confirmupload', 'Uploading Interior File', 'Processing Interior File', '*.pdf; *.doc; *.docx; *.rtf', '', '419430400 B',
        universalAjaxHandler.handleOnClick.bind(universalAjaxHandler, [['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'show'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'update', 'Your Interior File cannot exceed 400 MB.'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_field_container', 'showError'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload', 'showError']]), universalAjaxHandler.handleOnClick.bind(universalAjaxHandler, [['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'show'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'update', 'The file you selected is empty. Please select another file.'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_field_container', 'showError'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload', 'showError']]), universalAjaxHandler.handleOnClick.bind(universalAjaxHandler, [['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'update', ''], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_results', 'hide'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload_field_container', 'hideError'], ['element', 'tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__upload', 'hideError']]), 'e2fae1cd4365a945d1b85c369ac342bd0fae3d626797cd12', 'a8bfdf6173bb60eff9b42c338610dc5b',
        '', 0, 100, false
    );
    window['form_bookinterior_interiorfile'].customRequestParams = {"fileType":"TSW_BOOK_INTERIOR"};
      });
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<div class="" id="bookInteriorWarning" style="display: none;">
<div class="bookInteriorWarning">
   <div class="warningTop"></div>
   <div class="warningIcon">
      <span class="warningText">WARNING:</span>
<span class="">Your book's physical properties were updated. Please resubmit your book's interior.</span>
   </div>
   <div class="clearer"></div>
</div><br>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</form>
```

When I use

```
document.querySelector("#tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadTextTarget").value = "test.pdf";
```

and click on Save Button, it does show the uploading progress, but, is stuck at 0%, so, maybe it is getting path from the

```
<input type="text" class="contentTextField formItemNormal" id="tsw_setup_book_interior_tsw_book_interior__uploadTextTarget" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 5px;" disabled="true">
```

but, that would be a security concern? Setting full path in the value also doesn't help and it is again stuck at 0%.

Maybe they are using AJAX file upload?

I am kinda lost at this point.
Is there any way to automate this upload?

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Edit:- If the above is not possible, is it there any way to handle the file dialog using Puppeteer?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1376 take a look

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did take a look, but, the thing is, even dragging and dropping the file on the upload button fails. It just opens up my pdf in the tab, instead of setting the file on the upload button. So, I don't think that will work?

Comment: Do you have update @KJ1

Comment: @ktutnik Yes, here:- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2946

Comment: A small note, for Playwright you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132097/