# Playwright: Upload files from non-input element that cannot be used page.setInputFiles?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm working on uploading files through non-input HTML tag on Playwright.

For example, you can use `setInputFiles` like this, and this works:

```js
await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', './headphone.png')
```

But apparently `setInputFiles` only works for input element, something like this will be error:

```js
await page.setInputFiles('label.ImageUpload__label ', './headphone.png');
```

The HTML I'm working on is like this:

```html
<div id="ImageUpload" class="ImageUpload u-marginB10">
        <label class="ImageUpload__label js-dragdrop-area" for="selectFileMultiple">
            <span class="ImageUpload__hide">drag and drop or select files</span>
            <span class="ImageUpload__text"><span class="js-dragdrop-num">10</span>up to</span>
        </label>
</div>
```

So, is it possible to upload files to such HTML elements with Playwright?

Comment: `elementHandle.setInputFiles(files[, options])` really expects `elementHandle` to point to an input element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NodeJs: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-filechooser

```
        page.on("filechooser", (fileChooser: FileChooser) => {
             fileChooser.setFiles(["/path/to/a/file"]);
        })
```

or using async await

```js
import path = require('path')

...

const fileChooserPromise = page.waitForEvent('filechooser')
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'drag and drop or select files' }).click()
const fileChooser = await fileChooserPromise
await fileChooser.setFiles([path.join(__dirname, 'example.jpg')])
```

Python: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-filechooser/

```
with page.expect_file_chooser() as fc_info:
    page.click("upload")
file_chooser = fc_info.value
file_chooser.set_files("/path/to/a/file")
```

Java: https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-filechooser

```
FileChooser fileChooser = page.waitForFileChooser(() -> 
page.click("upload"));
fileChooser.setFiles(Paths.get("myfile.pdf"));
```

Comment: Is that for python? Can I use the feature on node.js?

Comment: Here is the Python version of the above code: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-filechooser/

Answer (score 3):

To upload a file using Playwright use [`setInputFiles(selector, files[, options])`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-input-files) function. This method takes the selector of the input element and the path to the file you want to upload.

The `files` parameter value can be a relative path (relative to the current working directory) or an absolute path. I strongly suggest that you use an absolute path to ensure predictable behavior.

```
test("upload a file", async ({ page }) => {
  console.log(resolve(__dirname, "bar.png"));

  await page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload-file/");
  await page.locator('input[name="foo"]').click();
  await page
    .locator('input[name="foo"]')
    .setInputFiles(resolve(__dirname, "bar.png"));

  await page.click("input[type=submit]");
});
```

Alternatively, you can read the file into a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and dispatch `drop` event onto the target element with [`DataTransfer` payload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer). This is useful when you are testing a drag-and-drop area:

```
const dataTransfer = await page.evaluateHandle(
  async ({ fileHex, localFileName, localFileType }) => {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

    dataTransfer.items.add(
      new File([fileHex], localFileName, { type: localFileType })
    );

    return dataTransfer;
  },
  {
    fileHex: (await readFile(resolve(__dirname, "bar.png"))).toString("hex"),
    localFileName: fileName,
    localFileType: fileType,
  }
);

await page.dispatchEvent("#drop_zone", "drop", { dataTransfer });

await expect(page.locator("text=bar.png")).toBeVisible();
```

You can further simplify the above code using [`createDataTransfer` utility](https://github.com/punkpeye/playwright-utilities#createdatatransfer) from [`playwright-utilities`](https://github.com/punkpeye/playwright-utilities):

```
const dataTransfer = await createDataTransfer({
    page,
    filePath: resolve(__dirname, "bar.png"),
    fileName: "bar.png",
    fileType: "image/png",
  });

await page.dispatchEvent("#drop_zone", "drop", { dataTransfer });

await expect(page.locator("text=bar.png")).toBeVisible();
```

Try this example locally by cloning the [Playwright Playground repository](https://punkpeye@github.com/punkpeye/playwright-playground):

```bash
git clone --branch test/upload-file https://punkpeye@github.com/punkpeye/playwright-playground.git
cd playwright-playground
npm install
npx playwright test tests/upload-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another alternative to upload that worked in my case. We create a buffer from memory and drag and drop the file to the upload button.

```
// Read your file into a buffer.
const buffer = readFileSync('file.pdf');

// Create the DataTransfer and File
const dataTransfer = await scope.page.evaluateHandle((data) => {
    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    // Convert the buffer to a hex array
    const file = new File([data.toString('hex')], 'file.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });
    dt.items.add(file);
    return dt;
}, buffer);

// Now dispatch
await page.dispatchEvent('YOUR_TARGET_SELECTOR', 'drop', { dataTransfer });
```

if using typescript, add this to the top of the file:

```js
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';
```

Github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10667#issuecomment-998397241

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue so I decided to use **AutoIt** to upload files with Playwright.

AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating Windows GUI and general scripting.

I used AutoIT to handle the Windows File Upload dialog, which cannot be handled using Playwright.

---

### Creating Script

1. Download AutoIt: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/
2. Open SciTE Script Editor and type the followng:

```
WinWaitActive("Choose files")
Send("C:\ChromeDriver\text.txt") 
Send("{ENTER}")
```

If it does not work, change *Choose files* to whatever title is on the top left of the upload dialog.

3. Click save and name it something like upload.au3 and save it in the root directory of your test.

[Example of Save Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt9WC.png)

4. Right click your newly created file and click *Compile Script*

---

### Executing the script in your test

Create execFile function of child process modules in node.js. Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

Add this to the top of your .spec.ts test file:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var upload_script = function(){
   exec('upload.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)                  
    });  
}
```

Open the upload dialog, then call the function in your test

```
// Click Browse
await page.locator('#browse').click();

// Execute Upload Script
upload_script();
```

**You have to run your test headed or it will not work:**

npx playwright test --headed